# MasterDetailsPage header and details layout in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

[link to mockup layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI4Ox.png)

In Xamarin.Forms, we have MasterDetailsPage, but is it possible to layout as a header and master details page were the master details content only changes when navigating but not the header? I have an app that has a header that has a special function after being pressed by x seconds, doing the in every page is not a good idea. So I am looking for a solution that a MasterDetailsPage can have a header instead of the side menu and a Detail panel.

Answer (score 0):

Would the Xamarin Forms NavigationPage be suitable for what you are attempting?

Comment: I'll look onto that

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. NavigationPage is not really what I want because I need a way to customize the header as well and have an addition function. In UWP, we have Frame. Luckily Frame works too in Xamarin.

So here's the screenshot
[image]

Here's how to get the other page in a Frame

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FrameNav.Content = (new Page_Home()).Content;
    }
}
```